# Is possible to point that the type used for a generic method, should be an interface?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

Here is my generic method code:

```
  public static IT Activate<IT>(string path)
  {
        //some code here....
  }
```

I'd want to set that generic IT must be only an interface.

Is this possible?

Comment: Great answers below, but why do you want that restriction?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. You can however set a constraint on an interface-name. Not tested but I think that when you use that interface as base for all your interfaces, it could work. Not sure if it's worth the effort.

Comment: Check [`Constraint on Type Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx), you can't do this, but perhaps you already know which interface you want to use, in this case you can use `where T : <interface name>`

Comment: I need that restriction because that method finds if the assembly located on "path" contains any class that implements interface IT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no such constraint in C#, or in .NET generics in general. You'd have to check at execution time.

```
if (!typeof(IT).IsInterface)
{
    // Presumably throw an exception
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't constraint `IT` to any interface type and interface alone. The closest you have is the `class` constraint and it applies `to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of would be a runtime check in the static contructor.  Like this:

```
static MyClass<IT>()
{
    if(!typeof(IT).IsInterface)
    {
        throw new WhateverException("Oi, only use interfaces.");
    }
}
```

Using the static contructor hopefully means it will fail fast, so the developer would discover the mistake sooner.

Also the check will only run once of each type of IT, not every method call.  So won't get a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a quick test about the use of a base-interface. It's possible, but as I said, not sure if it's worth the effort or even if it's good practice.

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
}

public interface IInterface1 : IBaseInterface
{
        //some code here.... 
}

public interface IInterface2
{
        //some code here.... 
}

public class Class1
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Activate<IInterface1>("myPath");
        //Activate<IInterface2>("myPath"); ==> doesn't compile
    }

    public static IT Activate<IT>(string path) where IT : IBaseInterface
    {
        //some code here.... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Koen,  That won't force IT to be an interface.  IT could still be a class which derives from IBaseInterface.  But still, maybe better than nothing.  At least would it force people to stop and think before they could use the method.

Comment: @BuhBuh Correct. I've overlooked that possibility. But it would be pretty useless to derive from an empty interface and like you said would enforce people to think before using it.

Comment: So the interface-check at execution time looks to be the only solution here. I'm going to leave this answer here, so others won't make the same mistake as I did.